# I have a repetition error somewhere in my batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have been trying to make a visualization tool for a Chinese abacus for the past hour, for this I need to isolate every number of the answer, but when I try and do this it repeats some numbers in a seemingly meaningless pattern.  For example when I plug in 12344+1 it gives me 123345455 as the final echo.  I have been struggling for quite awhile and would love some assistance, I am still quite a beginner at batch so I really have no idea why this is happening.

P.S.
Sorry for the messiness, like I said, I'm new

```
    @echo off
    SET a1=O
    SET a2=O
    SET a3=O
    SET a4=O
    SET a5=O
    SET b1=I
    SET b2=I
    SET b3=I
    SET b4=I
    SET b5=I
    SET c1=I
    SET c2=I
    SET c3=I
    SET c4=I
    set c5=I
    set d1=O
    set d2=O
    set d3=O
    set d4=O
    set d5=O
    set e1=O
    set e2=O
    set e3=O
    set e4=O
    set e5=O
    set f1=O
    set f2=O
    set f3=O
    set f4=O
    set f5=O
    set g1=O
    set g2=O
    set g3=O
    set g4=O
    set g5=O
    :beginning
    echo.
    echo Welcome to the virtual Abacus.
    echo.
    echo I am only a visualization and do not compute in the same way as an abacus.
    echo.
    echo Please be kind, as I can only handle single operator equations,
    echo and keep the answers to below 100,000 too please.
    echo ---------
    echo %a1% %a2% %a3% %a4% %a5% 
    echo %b1% %b2% %b3% %b4% %b5% 
    echo ---------
    echo %c1% %c2% %c3% %c4% %c5% 
    echo %d1% %d2% %d3% %d4% %d5% 
    echo %e1% %e2% %e3% %e4% %e5% 
    echo %f1% %f2% %f3% %f4% %f5% 
    echo %g1% %g2% %g3% %g4% %g5% 
    echo ---------
    set /p Equation=What is your question?
    set /a result=%Equation%
    set Res1=%result:~0,1%
    set Res2=%result:~1,2%
    set Res3=%result:~2,3%
    set Res4=%result:~3,4%
    set Res5=%result:~4,5%
    echo %Res1%%Res2%%Res3%%Res4%%Res5%
    pause
```

Comment: read again the output of `set /?`: `set Res3=%result:~2,3%` takes a substing starting at position `2` (starts counting with zero!), with a lenght of `3`. You want `set Res3=%result:~2,1%` (same for the other lines)

Comment: Thank you so much, your a real life saver.

Comment: One of you should post that answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your "question" have several drawbacks and confusing points. The title is meaningless and the posting of the whole abacus visualization code have *no relation* with the problem, that is just a substring problem (not a "repetition error"). You should learn to identify the problem by yourself and post much more concise and clear questions...

If you post unrelated code you may get unrelated "answers", like this one:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "rods=13"
cls
echo/
echo Visualization of a Japanese Soroban abacus
rem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soroban

:loop
echo/
set "number="
set /P "number=Enter a number: "
echo/
if not defined number goto :EOF

set "number= %number%"
for /L %%j in (0,1,7) do set "row%%j="
set "line="
for /L %%i in (%rods%,-1,1) do (
   set "line=!line!--"
   set "row7=!row7! !number:~-%%i,1!"
)

for /L %%i in (%rods%,-1,1) do (
   set /A "digit=!number:~-%%i,1!" 2>NUL
   if !digit! geq 5 (
      set "row6=!row6! |"
      set "row5=!row5! O"
      set /A digit-=5
   ) else (
      set "row6=!row6! O"
      set "row5=!row5! |"
   )
   for /L %%j in (0,1,4) do (
      if !digit! equ %%j (
         set "row%%j=!row%%j! |"
      ) else (
         set "row%%j=!row%%j! O"
      )
   )
)

echo %row7%
echo %line%
for %%j in (6,5) do echo !row%%j!
echo %line%
for /L %%j in (0,1,4) do echo !row%%j!
echo %line%
echo/
goto loop
```